# Cassandra UDF, UDA. Exit the UDF and UDA at first key repetition in map

Tags: cassandra, distinct, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions, database-performance

I would like to exit at on first key repetition from the function and aggregate 
and return the map. That will help me in improving the performance of my query. As currently it goes through all the records.

I have an aggregate function

```
create aggregate getdistinct(val1 int, val2 text)
SFUNC createdistinctmap 
STYPE map<int,text> 
INITCOND ();
```

and a UDF

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION db.createdistinctmap ( container map<int,text>, val1 int, val2 text) 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    RETURNS map<int,text>
    LANGUAGE java AS 
      $$ 
String val2String = (String) container.get(val1);
if(val2String == null){
    container.put(val1, val2);
}
else{
    System.exit(0); 
    //I would like to exit at this point from the function and aggregate 
    //and return the container on first key repetition
}
         return container; $$ 
    ;
```

call is done like this

```
select getdistict(column1, column2) from table;
```

Comment: Your function/aggregation query doesn't seem to target a particular partition_key. So design the model in such a way, rather than querying everything.

Comment: I am trying to get distinct values of a non-partition key, against the partition-key value. In the above code val1 is that non-parition key, and the val2 is the partition key. The result ultimately will be different keys but same value for all keys.